# Give Password Based on number of users with the same tag

Tags: java, passwords

Hi im doing a project for college and after finishing the majority of the code i hit a speedbump i need to register three types of users and one of them uses the department building nick as a basis for the password attribution i have an arraylist for each type, the password for this type of user should composed by the nick of the department and the number of registered users in that department so i wrote the code below which works which kinda works but the first password always gives me an empty field, the code i have is:

```
public String GivePasswordStaff(String signdept){

    int counter = 0;
    String password = "";

        Iterator<Staff> liststaff = staff.iterator();

        while (liststaff.hasNext()) {
            Staff lists = liststaff.next();

            if(signdept.equals(lists.getSigndept())){
                counter++;
                password = signdept + counter;

             }

       }
        return password;
    }
```

The thing is i need the first passwords of each department to be nick1 and with this code the first one is always "" and the second it gives the password i want except if i input a password for a different department in which case it always start with nick0 what can i do to solve this

Thanks in advance to all that reply

Comment: What if user don't have any department then in that case what will be the password?

Comment: @Bilbo Baggins There is already a condition when this type of user is registered that demands that a department must be registered in order to register this type of user

Comment: but shouldn't you be able to add the user irrespective of department? whether the department exists or not, they shouldn't be dependent.

Comment: @Bilbo Baggins You can add a user thats independent of the department just not this type of user this user needs to be created like this

Comment: if I understand correctly you want the first password of a user to be nick1 always for first user for 2nd user it would be nick2 ? correct?

Comment: @Bilbo Baggins Yes if the user is in the same department the password will be for the first nick1, for the second nick2 and so on, when you change and do for another department it will be nick1 for the first, nick2 for the second and always like this

Answer (score 0):

An ugly but posible solution would be to assign the desired name for the password at the declaration:

```
String password = signdept+"1";
```

For the part about nick0, try to write some example, I can't understand what happens. What do you mean by "except if i input a password for a different department"?

Comment: That could work in theory but its a bit rough around the edges and wouldn't work a 100%. What i meant by "except if i input a password for a different department" is when i create a new user staff but for a different department the first password for that user will always be nick0

Comment: @Reynaud0000 The password comes out as nick0 or it have to be it but its not implemented yet?

Comment: The password for each staff is basically the nick of the department in which you want to register a new user and the number of registered  users in this department so the first password for the first user registered in a new department should always be nick1